# align div's on one horizontal line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 horizontal divs. 
Each div contains three child divs:

- Header div
- line div
- text div

How can I achieve that all the line div's (I mean the div that creates a line between header text and content text) will be aligned horizontally?
I need all the horizontal line divs (class="h_line") on one horizontal line.

The horizontal lines are highlighted with red arrows.

[image]

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3bgtyjh/).

Please note that I use [bigtext](https://github.com/DanielHoffmann/jquery-bigtext/). 
That library centers the text in its div.

Html

```
<div class="ThirdSectionTextArea">

              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell1">
              </div>
              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2">
                  <span class="bigtext">  
                  <div class="header_allroundservice leftalign">
                      HEADER 
                  </div>
                    <div class="h_line"></div>
                  <div class="leftalign">
                        SOME Content
                  </div>
                  </span>
              </div>
              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell3">
                  <span class="bigtext">
                    <div class="leftalign uppercase">
                        HEADER 
                    </div>
                     <div class="h_line"></div>
                    <div class="leftalign">
                        SOME Content
                    </div>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell4">
                <span class="bigtext">
                  <div class="leftalign uppercase">
                       HEADER
                  </div>
                  <div class="h_line"></div>
                  <div class="leftalign">
                       SOME CONTENT
                  </div>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell5">
              </div>
```

Comment: could you add some code please?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Saying that any title text vary in length and span over more than 1 line and some are in just 1 line, is that correct? ... If yes, check my answer as it does exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume any title text can vary in length and span over more than 1 line when some are in just 1 line, is that correct?

In such case you need rows, like below sample, if you want it to be dynamically adjusting. If not, you need to have fixed heights on the title.

```css
table, body {
  background-color: #ccc;  
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
.cell:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: orange;
  border-right: 5px solid #ccc;
}
.cell:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-left: 5px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 5px solid #ccc;
}
.cell:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lime;
  border-left: 5px solid #ccc;
}
.inner {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      First
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Second<br>
      2 lines
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      Third
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">
        First
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">
        Second<br>
        2 lines
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner">
        Third<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
        with many lines<br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You set all the divs to table elements. Couldn't I use directly html table? And using a table: Isn't that a problem when I want to use the big text library to fit text into its parent div? Because the table seems to expand for some reason even when there has been set fixed size to it...

Comment: @jublikon I updated how to solve max-height when using display:table, where I added an inner div to do the trick as table-cell don't respond to max-height. When it comes to the use of table tag, this trick is mainly to make your titles to take up the same space, despite of amount of lines and you shouldn't start using table tags. This can be achieved using plain div's as well though the code structure is much cleaner like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use display-inline

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
}
.block {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #84c300;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
.block .title {
  padding: 5px;
}

.block .text {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try my JS fiddle code. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.box-1 {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.box-1:first-child {
    background: red;
}
.box-1:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}
.box-1:nth-child(3) {
    background: brown;
}
.box-1:nth-child(4) {
    background: orange;
}
.heading {
    min-height:40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.heading h1 {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:11px;
}
.text p{
    color:#fff;
    font-size:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box-1">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>
            SOFTWARE- UND <br> DATENBANKENTWICKLUNG 
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Unsere Kernkompetenz liegt im Bereich Softwareentwicklung 
            und Datenbank- programmierung. Hierbei legen wir den Focus 
            auf die Steigerung der Effizienz und  Transparenz Ihrer 
            Geschäftsprozesse. Wir stecken viel Know-how in eine 
            einfache  Bedienbarkeit der Software – selbst wenn komplexe 
            Vorgänge abgebildet werden. Denn Sie sollen Ihre Software 
            schließlich intuitiv bedienen können, nicht wir.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-1">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>
            SOFTWARE- UND <br> DATENBANKENTWICKLUNG 
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Unsere Kernkompetenz liegt im Bereich Softwareentwicklung 
            und Datenbank- programmierung. Hierbei legen wir den Focus 
            auf die Steigerung der Effizienz und  Transparenz Ihrer 
            Geschäftsprozesse. Wir stecken viel Know-how in eine 
            einfache  Bedienbarkeit der Software – selbst wenn komplexe 
            Vorgänge abgebildet werden. Denn Sie sollen Ihre Software 
            schließlich intuitiv bedienen können, nicht wir.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-1">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>
            SOFTWARE- UND <br> DATENBANKENTWICKLUNG 
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Unsere Kernkompetenz liegt im Bereich Softwareentwicklung 
            und Datenbank- programmierung. Hierbei legen wir den Focus 
            auf die Steigerung der Effizienz und  Transparenz Ihrer 
            Geschäftsprozesse. Wir stecken viel Know-how in eine 
            einfache  Bedienbarkeit der Software – selbst wenn komplexe 
            Vorgänge abgebildet werden. Denn Sie sollen Ihre Software 
            schließlich intuitiv bedienen können, nicht wir.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-1">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>
            SOFTWARE- UND <br> DATENBANKENTWICKLUNG 
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Unsere Kernkompetenz liegt im Bereich Softwareentwicklung 
            und Datenbank- programmierung. Hierbei legen wir den Focus 
            auf die Steigerung der Effizienz und  Transparenz Ihrer 
            Geschäftsprozesse. Wir stecken viel Know-how in eine 
            einfache  Bedienbarkeit der Software – selbst wenn komplexe 
            Vorgänge abgebildet werden. Denn Sie sollen Ihre Software 
            schließlich intuitiv bedienen können, nicht wir.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`Float divs with same heading height`(https://jsfiddle.net/ua7hmwsn/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
when I add some text to the headline of your fiddle the horizontal divider line ("h_line")line is lower that the other horizontal divider lines ("h_line")